# change zip contents from zip data stream without extraction - node

Tags: node.js, stream, zip

i have an endpoint in a nest server with Typescript which gets a zip file from another service.

i want to change the file names of this zip file without extracting them locally but i cant find a way.
I cant find a way to create a zip file from a stream of data.

```
//get data from stream
formFileContent = downloadFileResponse.data;

//here need to change zip file names
```

any idea how to do this ? any library or something ?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer :

```
var zip = new admZip(data);
var newZip = new admZip();

      zip.getEntries().forEach((zipEntry, i) => {
        const entryData = zipEntry.getData()
        
        var newFileName = cart[i]. '.pdf'
    
        newZip.addFile(newFileName, entryData);
      });

      return new StreamableFile(newZip.toBuffer());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).